# Сколько заголовков h1 должно быть на странице документа HTML5?

Tags: seo, html5

Всем привет.

Вопрос, наверное, больше к СЕОшникам, чем к фронт-эндерам. Недавно сдал верстку, ее уже залили на хост, поработал бэк-эндер, и настало время сео-оптимизации. Вот именно после этого прожект-менеджер отписала, что СЕОшники немного посмеялись над моей работой. 
Я в курсе, что, учитывая стандарты HTML4 или XHTML, заголовок H1 на странице должен быть один. НО! Ведь в HTML5 с появлением новых блочных элементов (article, section, main, footer...) заголовков первого уровня (Н1) может быть несколько. Вот так приблизительно выглядит прототип сайта, с пометками, где я использовал H1. 
[клац по ссылке](http://webkupas.ru/seo.jpg)

С точки зрения валидности, все верно. Действительно ли я затупил в верстке с точки зрения СЕО?

Comment: я как-то думал, что верстальщику оптимизация - не сильно приоритетная задача...для этого же есть отдельные спецы

Comment: И мне так кажется, но если мы будем работать и дальше в команде, лучше найти консенсус. Я в принципе к критике отношусь вполне нормально, меня просто немного задело, что с моей работы смеялись, в том случае, если я все сделал верно...

Comment: @kupas, не берусь утверждать, какова ситуация на самом деле, но в отрасли полно напыщенных и самодовольных людей, которые *знают* всё про всё.

Comment: Почему то все упадают по СЕО, которая нужна только кучке менеджеров, и забывают о NFB (о слепых, о тех, кому тяжело пользоваться мышкой и так далее). И вот, Там, правильно расставленные заголовки, помогают понять, что вообще творится на странице. И ответ на вопрос - h1 должно быть ровно столько, сколько это нужно.

Answer (score 7):

Цитата с [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/verstka-na-html5/glavnaya-stranitsa)

> Каждый блок со ссылкой и её описанием обрамлён тегом , сама ссылка располагается внутри тега , который в свою очередь находится внутри . Такая логика может показаться странной — зачем нам , когда на странице он уже есть, и к чему столько тегов ? В HTML5 своя логика построения структуры документа, которая отличается от привычной схемы HTML4. В предыдущей версии HTML иерархия блоков строилась на основе тегов .... Соответственно,  задавал заголовок страницы,  и  подзаголовки. Чтобы схема документа строилась правильно, на странице должен быть только один . **Спецификация HTML5 устанавливает алгоритм генерации схемы документа, включающий в себя новые семантические теги. Этот алгоритм говорит, что теги  и  создают новый раздел. А в HTML5 каждый раздел может содержать собственный тег .**

Comment: Вобщем сделал для себя новое открытие, посредствам опытных в этом вопросе людей) Цитирую ответ мне на одном из фрумов:

"SelenIT: Редактор W3C-шной версии спеки настаивает(http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/), что нельзя полагаться на вложенность секций и нужно дублировать структуру заголовков по старинке, уровнями. Потому что куча софта еще не освоила новый алгоритм, и есть риск, что из-за слабого внедрения алгоритм вообще грохнут.

Три года назад несколько заголовков H1 считались ошибкой SEO (хоть и не особо критичной). "

Comment: Далее опираясь уже на этот ответ, я нашел еще несколько полезных материалов, вот один из них:
http://seo-mayak.com/seo-prodvizhenie/tonkosti-prodvizheniya/pravilnaya-struktura-zagolovkov-sajta-html-tegi-h1-h6-i-ix-vliyanie-na-prodvizhenie.html
И выводы, сделанные автором в процессе переписки с Яндексом и личного эксперимента:
(в следуюшем коменте)

Comment: Вывод №1. Заголовки сайта должны иметь четкую иерархию. Т.е. начиная с заголовка сайта (h1) и так далее вниз по цепочке.

Вывод №2. HTML тег h1 не влияет на ранжирование. Роботу не важн, в какой тег заключен заголовок статьи. Было бы глупо предполагать обратное, при современных, мощных аналитических технологиях.

Вывод №3. Заголовком может быть даже изображение, оптимизированное должным образом. Можно без всяких опасений использовать в качества заголовка сайта любое изображение, напирмер, с логотипом.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ

> Цитата

Здравствуйте, Cool SMM!

У нас нет жестких требований к заголовкам H1. Вы можете оформлять их в соответствии с Вашими предпочтениями. Наличие нескольких заголовков H1 не является негативным фактором, но мы рекомендуем оформлять заголовки в тексте так, чтобы они помогали быстрее сориентироваться пользователю на странице.

--

С уважением, Платон Щукин
Служба поддержки Яндекса
https://yandex.ru/support/

> Цитата