# Может ли быть более одного h1 заголовка на странице?

Tags: вёрстка, seo

Можно ли делать более одного `<h1>` заголовка на странице? Т.е. будет ли это семантически правильно? И не создаст ли это проблем для SEO и индексации сайта в будущем?

Просто когда-то давно где-то слышал что `<h1>` должен быть только 1 на странице.

Comment: нет, заголовок h1 должен быть только один.

Comment: по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) нет никаких ограничений на количество заголовков

Comment: Зачем задавать вопрос, если он уже задан?

Comment: У меня на сайте http://pusiki.com/ выдает 13 страниц с повторяющимся Н1. Вот только как эту проблему убрать я понять не могу, к большому сожалению. Может это в коде нужно исправлять, подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H1 - заголовок первого уровня.

Для поисковых систем несколько H1, всё-равно, что для Вас несколько названий одной статьи.

Правильный ответ: лучше всё-же использовать 1 H1

Comment: можете привести какие-нибудь подтверждения того, что _Для поисковых систем несколько H1, всё-равно, что для Вас несколько названий одной статьи._?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, их _жизненный опыт_ ничего не стоит, потому что от него никак не зависят алгоритмы ранжирования яндекс и гугл. Поэтому то, что им могло случайно помочь один раз, вполне может навредить или никак не повлиять второй раз

Answer (score 6):

`h1` - это элемент верхнего уровня в оглавлении. Т.е. название раздела / главы / чего-нибудь еще.

Нет никаких проблем с несколькими элементами h1 на странице - напротив, увидеть только 1 "главный" заголовок в автоматически построенном оглавлении было бы странно.

Comment: С логической точки зрения вы правы, но будет ли правильно все так с семантической? Вот к примеру нашел [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/357664/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-h1-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-html5?rq=1) парня засмеяли SEO-шники за дублирование h1 заголовков

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev я про семантику и писал. А сеошников шлите сюда - будем смеяться над ними, с пруфами (которые привел автор того вопроса, на который вы сослались).

Answer (score 0):

Долгое время считалось, что на одной веб-странице можно иметь только один элемент h1. Но в последнем стандарте ХТМЛ5 имеются **[семантические элементы](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)**, с которыми вы можете сегментировать/фрагментировать исходный код вашей страницы. В документации указано, что основные элементы article + section должны иметь какой-то элемент h, но не нет директивы для обязательной последовательности этих элементов. Однако, (Дьявол спрятан в деталях), вы должны понимать, что поисковики и браузеры при сканировании вашей страницы создают **[объектную модель документа DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)**. Из **[этой документации W3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)**, вы можете видеть, что элемент h1, является одним из основных элементов для создания DOM. При нескольких элементах h1 возможна задержка с определением главенства этих элементов - от какого начинать. Из-за этого может понизиться скорость загрузки веб-страницы, а это в настоящее время один из основных факторов поискового ранжирования. Поисковые системы используют заголовки для индексации структуры и содержания ваших веб-страниц. **[Статья W3 об этом](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)** + *[***HTML5 Doctor***](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/)* + **[статья SearchEngineLand](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)**. **Мой ответ**: можно применять много элементов h1 на одной веб-странице, но корректнее применять только один такой элемент и выдерживать последовательность и вложенность всех элементов h. Для определения структуры сайта с элементами h, я рекомендую вам применять **[валидатор W3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. Выберите фильтр outline и контролируйте структуру вашего сайта/страницы внизу, в секциях Heading-level outline и Structural outline. **[Пример последовательности элементов h](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showoutline=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fsweden-tourist.com%2Fsights%2Fen%2Fkungslott-en.html)**.